# Counting two ways, $\sum \binom{n}{k} \binom{m}{n-k} = \binom{n+m}{n}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

prove by counting two ways:

[image]

I though to prove the right hand side I would say:
Let n represent a number of boys and m a number of girls. We want to choose a group of n from boys and girls. But for the left hand side I want to keep the variables m and n girls and boys. But I don't know what k will be. Suggestions?

Comment: Hint: replace $\binom nk$ by $\binom n{n-k}$.

Comment: $(1+x)^m(1+x)^n=(1+x)^{m+n}$

Comment: See also: [Combinatorial interpretation for the identity $\sum\limits_i\binom{m}{i}\binom{n}{j-i}=\binom{m+n}{j}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/91457)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose  $n \leq m $.

Then if you want to choose $n$ people, you can choose $k$ boys in $\binom{n}{k}$ ways and $n-k$ girls in $\binom{m}{n-k}$ ways , for $k \in \{0,1, \dots n\}$.

So we have $$\sum_{k = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \binom{m}{n-k} = \binom{n+m}{n}$$

Answer (score 0):

If you are choosing $k$ girls, then exactly $k$ of the boys will not be chosen (since you are choosing as many children as there are boys).