# Prove that this sum of products of binomial coefficient can be simplified like this

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

$a , b, c$ are positive integers such that ${a}\geq{b+c}$.

Prove that $$\sum_{i=0}^{b}{\binom{a}{i+c}\binom{b}{i}}=\binom{a+b}{b+c}$$

Comment: Share your own attempts at this problem. People will want to help you more if you do so

Comment: This is a problem i created when i was solving another combinatorics problem. I already knew the answer.

Comment: Better start at $i=0$.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1659106/prove-that-sum-limits-k-0m-binommk-binomnrk-binommnmr-using

Comment: Ah, the beauty of combinatorics, there are always multiple solutions to a problem. I guess it is unfair to expect people to give a particular answer to the problem. I will share my methods and just close the question.

Answer (score 2):

$\binom{a}{i+c}$ is the coefficient of $x^{i+c}$ from $(x+1)^{a}$ while $\binom{b}{i}$ is the coefficient of $\frac{1}{x^{i}}$ from $(\frac{1}{x}+1)^{b}$.

$\sum_{i=0}^{b}\binom{a}{i+c}\binom{b}{i}$ is the coefficient of $x^{c}$ from $(x+1)^{a}(\frac{1}{x}+1)^b=\frac{(x+1)^{a+b}}{x^{b}}$ which is $\binom{a+b}{b+c}$.

Answer (score 1):

Write the first term on the left side as $\binom{a}{ a - c - i}$ and the term in the right side as $\binom{a + b}{ a - c}$. (Hypergeometric distribution?)

Answer (score 1):

By Vandermonde,
$$\sum_{i=0}^{b}{\binom{a}{i+c}\binom{b}{i}}=\sum_{i=0}^{b}{\binom{a}{a-c-i}\binom{b}{i}}=\binom{a+b}{a-c}=\binom{a+b}{b+c}$$