# Verify the following combinatorial identity: $\sum_{k=0}^{r} \binom{m}{k}\binom{n}{r-k} = \binom{m+n}{r}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, combinatorial-proofs

$$\sum_{k=0}^{r} \binom{m}{k}\binom{n}{r-k} = \binom{m+n}{r}$$

Nice, so I've proven some combinatorial identities before via induction, other more simple ones by committee selection models.... But this one is weird, induction doesn't even seem feasible here without things getting nasty, and the summation on the left is not making things easier. Can anyone help?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity

Comment: It's a small thing, but try defining $N=n+m$ to eliminate $n$; the combinatorial intuition may be easier.

Comment: @Semiclassical thanks for the good idea.

Comment: This seems to be the same question as: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91457/combinatorial-interpretation-for-the-identity-sum-limits-i-binommi-binomn or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337923/vandermondes-identity-summations-with-binomial-coefficients (You can find many other questions about this identity on this site.)

Comment: Since you have tagged this ([tag:combinatorial-proof]), are you looking exclusively for [combinatorial arguments](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/combinatorial-proofs/info), or are you just looking for any proof of this identity?

Comment: I tried to find a question similar to mine and failed. Thank you for your suggestions. I was just looking for a better general understanding of this identity (which I got thanks to the nice people on this site). I'll try to be more clear with my tags next time to help you understand what I am aiming for.

Answer (score 3):

Note that there exist different $m+n$ balls and two bags.

One bag contains $m$ balls and the other has $n$.

What is the number of choosing $r$ balls ? Clearly $$ _{m+n}C_r$$

But we divided into two bag. : The number of choosing $k$ balls in the first bag is $ _mC_k $ And we must choose $r-k$ balls in second. The number of possibility is $ _nC_{r-k}$ So we have $$ _mC_k\ _nC_{r-k}$$

Comment: Thanks, I see what you did.

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic double counting argument. We will count how many ways we can choose $r$ balls from $m+n$ balls.

If we place $m+n$ balls in a single urn, then the right hand side counts the number of ways we can select $r$ balls from the urn containing $m+n$ balls.

Suppose now we place $m$ balls in one urn and $n$ balls in the other. I can select a total of $r$ things from these two two urns by choosing $k$ balls from the first urn and $r-k$ balls from the second urn. Thus there are $\binom{m}{k}\binom{n}{r-k}$ ways for this selection to happen. Summing over all possible values of $k$ will tell us the total number of ways we can choose $r$ balls from $m+n$ balls.

Comment: This approach is direct, I understand it as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short inductive proof, that may however not be as illuminating as a combinatorial argument:

**Theorem.**
For all nonnegative integers $r$, $m$ and $n$, there holds *Vandermonde's
identity*
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{r}\binom{m}{k}\binom{n}{r-k}=\binom{m+n}{r}.
$$

**Proof.**
Let $f(m,n,r)=\sum_{k=0}^{r}\binom{m}{k}\binom{n}{r-k}$, and use the
convention that $\binom{m}{k}=0$ unless $0\leq k\leq m$. Note that
$f(0,n,r)=\binom{n}{r}$. Assume now that
$$
f(m,n,r)=\binom{m+n}{r}
$$
for fixed $m$, and for all $n$ and $r$. From this and from Pascal's rule
$\binom{m+1}{k}=\binom{m}{k-1}+\binom{m}{k}$, we find
\begin{eqnarray*}
f(m+1,n,r)&=&f(m,n,r-1)+f(m,n,r) \\
&=&\binom{m+n}{r-1}+\binom{m+n}{r}=\binom{m+n+1}{r}.\Box
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 1):

Using the binomial theorem, we have
$$
\begin{align}
(1+x)^m(1+x)^n
&=\sum_{j=0}^m\binom{m}{j}x^j\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x^k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{m+n}\color{#C00000}{\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{m}{j}\binom{n}{k-j}}x^k
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
(1+x)^{m+n}
&=\sum_{k=0}^{m+n}\color{#C00000}{\binom{m+n}{k}}x^k
\end{align}
$$
Compare the coefficients of $x^k$.

Comment: Same idea simultaneously :)

Answer (score 0):

An other way to proceed is to write:

$ (x+1)^{m+n} = (x+1)^n*(x+1)^m $

Then you develop each term using the binomial formula and you evaluate the coefficient of the term $x^r$ on the right, knowing that the one on the left is $C_{n+m}^r$. The proof is quite straightforward when you go down this path.

You get a double sum with two index i,j and to find the coefficient of $x^r$ you take each term that verifies i+j=r .

Does that help?