# Prove: ${n\choose 0}{m\choose k}+{n\choose 1}{m\choose {k-1}}+...+{n\choose k}{m\choose 0}={{m+n}\choose k}$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

Prove: ${n\choose 0}{m\choose k}+{n\choose 1}{m\choose {k-1}}+...+{n\choose k}{m\choose 0}={{m+n}\choose k}$

Is it possible to use Pascal's identity or writing binomial coefficients with factorials?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde's_identity

Comment: There is a combinatorial argument: taking $k$ items from $2$ piles respectively of $n$ and $m$ items is equivalent to take $i$ items in the first $n$-pile and $k-i$-items in the second $m$-pile. Then, you sum over all the possibilities for $i$.

Comment: You can equate coefficients in $(1+x)^m(1+x)^n=(1+x)^{m+n}$, which is an algebraic way of expressing the combinatorial argument given by @MoebiusCorzer

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Vandermonde's Identity : Summations with binomial coefficients](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337923/vandermondes-identity-summations-with-binomial-coefficients) and of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91457/combinatorial-interpretation-for-the-identity-sum-limits-i-binommi-binomn?lq=1), which has a nice combinatorial answer.