# What is the theory behind a simple pattern involving binomial coefficients?

Tags: combinatorics, soft-question

These binomial equations are all true.

$\binom{7}{4} = \binom{4}{4} + 3[ \binom{4}{3} +  \binom{4}{2}] +  \binom{4}{1}$

$\binom{8}{4} = \binom{5}{4} + 3[ \binom{5}{3} +  \binom{5}{2}] +  \binom{5}{1}$

$\binom{9}{4} = \binom{6}{4} + 3[ \binom{6}{3} +  \binom{6}{2}] +  \binom{6}{1}$

$\dots$

> Is this the result of some general binomial identity or theory?

**My work**

I stumbled upon this while working with a recurrence relation in $(m,n)$ with $m,n \in \Bbb Z^+$
that I was trying to put into closed form.

Comment: Google "Vandermode Identity" and see this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91457/combinatorial-interpretation-for-the-identity-sum-limits-i-binommi-binomn

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit I will review - thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By repeatedly applying Pascal's Theorem:

$$\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{4} &=\binom{n-1}{4}+\binom{n-1}{3}
 \\ &=\left(\binom{n-2}{4}+\binom{n-2}{3}\right)+\left(\binom{n-2}{3}+\binom{n-2}{2}\right)
 \\ &=\left(\left(\binom{n-3}{4}+\binom{n-3}{3}\right)+\left(\binom{n-3}{3}+\binom{n-3}{2}\right)\right)+\left(\left(\binom{n-3}{3}+\binom{n-3}{2}\right)+\left(\binom{n-3}{2}+\binom{n-3}{1}\right)\right)
\\ &= \binom{n-3}{4}+3\binom{n-3}{3}+3\binom{n-3}{2}+\binom{n-3}{1}
\end{align*}
$$