# Formula for binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Does someone know, if the subsequent formula holds for $m \ge n \ge i \ge 1$ and if yes, can give a reference. 
$$\sum_{k=i}^{m-n+i}\binom{k}{i}\binom{m-k}{n-i} = \binom{m+1}{n+1}$$
Thank you very much!

Comment: I believe it's the same formula as in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73015/proof-of-sum-0-le-k-le-t-t-k-choose-rk-choose-s-t1-choose-rs1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is equation (5.26) on page 169 of
 *Concrete Mathematics (2nd edition)* 
 by Ronald Graham, Donald Knuth, and Oren Patashnik.

**Corrected:** For integers $m,n\geq0$ and integers $\ell,q$ with  $\ell+q\geq 0$
we have
$$\sum_{-q\leq k\leq \ell}{q+k\choose n}{\ell-k\choose m}={\ell+q+1\choose m+n+1}.$$

---

Let's now substitute your variables $i\geq 0$ and $n-i\geq 0$ in the bottom 
to obtain
$$\sum_{-q\leq k\leq \ell}{q+k\choose i}{\ell-k\choose n-i}={\ell+q+1\choose n+1}.$$

In fact, since you have assumed $i>0$, we get even more
$$\sum_{i-q\leq k\leq \ell}{q+k\choose i}{\ell-k\choose n-i}={\ell+q+1\choose n+1}.$$
That's because ${q+k\choose i}=0$ when $q+k<i$.

Redefining the $k$ variable gives
$$\sum_{i\leq k\leq \ell+q}{k\choose i}{\ell+q-k\choose n-i}={\ell+q+1\choose n+1}.$$

Letting $m=\ell+q$ gives 
$$\sum_{i\leq k\leq m}{k\choose i}{m-k\choose n-i}={m+1\choose n+1}.$$

Is this the same as your sum? Yes!

1. If $n=i$, then this is obvious.
2. When $n>i$, then ${m-k\choose n-i}=0$ for $k>m-n+i$ anyway.

Comment: Byron, there are a couple of typos in the book for that sum.  The summation should be for $-q \leq k \leq \ell$, and it's valid for integers $m,n \geq 0$ and integer $\ell + q \geq 0$.  (The corrections are listed on Knuth's web site.)

Comment: @Mike Yikes! I should have checked that. Thanks.

Comment: Knuth's books tend to have few errors; I was surprised when I discovered this one.

Comment: Thanks to you both, Byron and Mike. But I think both sums are not quite the same: In Knuth's formula there are $l+q+1$ summands (equals the "nominator" in the right-hand-side binomial), while in mine there are $m-n+1$ sumands corresponding to the difference of the "nominator" and "denominator" of the r.h.s-binomial. Accordingly, I was able to transform Knuth's formula into $$\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{k}{i}\binom{m-k}{n-i}=\binom{m+1}{n+1}$$

Comment: Anyway, my formula can be proved by a quite simple induction. Tanks again.

Comment: @Ralph I'm glad you found your answer. Anyway, I have added the change of variables argument, just for fun.

Comment: @MikeSpivey, did you claim your $2.18?

Comment: @Byron: Yeah, sure. Thanks for showing. I should also have seen that in the formula in my comment above one can assume $k \ge i$ (otherwise first binom is zero) and $m-k \ge n-i$ (otherwise 2nd binom zero).

Comment: @Bruno: I wasn't the first to discover it, so no. :)  I do have a check from Knuth for finding an error in *The Art of Computer Programming*, though.

Comment: @Ralph Careful with that second one, you can only assume that $m-k\geq n-i$ provided that $n-i>0$.

Comment: @MikeSpivey Ha ha! I also have a check from Knuth. It's framed and on my office wall.

Comment: Byron, mine is framed as well.  The check itself is worth much more than the money. :)

Comment: Mike and Byron - I am jealous. It's ironic that I wrote $2.18 above, and no-one corrected me. :)

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k = i}^{m - n + i}{k \choose i}{m - k \choose n - i} & =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{k + i \choose i}{m - k - i \choose n - i} =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{k + i \choose k}{m - k - i \choose m - k - n}
\\[5mm] & =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\bracks{{-i - 1 \choose k}\pars{-1}^{k}}
\bracks{{i - n - 1\choose m - k - n}\pars{-1}^{m - k - n}}
\\[5mm] & =
\pars{-1}^{m - n}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{-i - 1 \choose k}
\bracks{z^{m - k - n}}\pars{1 + z}^{i - n - 1}
\\[5mm] & =
\pars{-1}^{m - n}\bracks{z^{m - n}}\pars{1 + z}^{i - n - 1}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{-i - 1 \choose k}z^{k}
\\[5mm] & =
\pars{-1}^{m - n}\bracks{z^{m - n}}\pars{1 + z}^{i - n - 1}\,
\pars{1 + z}^{-i - 1} =
\pars{-1}^{m - n}\bracks{z^{m - n}}\pars{1 + z}^{-n - 2}
\\[5mm] & =
\pars{-1}^{m - n}{-n - 2 \choose m - n} =
\pars{-1}^{m - n}\bracks{{m + 1 \choose m - n}\pars{-1}^{m - n}} =
\bbx{m + 1 \choose n + 1}
\end{align}