# How to prove the binomial identity $\binom{n + 1}{a + b + 1} = \sum_{k = 0}^n \binom{k}{a}\binom{n - k}{b}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-theorem, combinatorial-proofs

Prove the identity:
$$\binom{n + 1}{a + b + 1} = \sum_{k = 0}^n \binom{k}{a}\binom{n - k}{b}$$

So far I understand the left side represents how many ways there are picking a+b+1 elements from a set (lets say X) with cardinality n+1. The right side as far as I understand means how many ways there are choosing a elements from a set with cardinality k and then number of ways choosing b elements from a set with n-k cardinality. However I do not see how adding all these sums as k goes from 0 to n adds up to the left hand side.
Thanks for the help.
*(Side note: I wish to prove this without generating functions or Vandermondes identity, but with a counting argument).*

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck.

Comment: Show us some of your work.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig pls see your reputations

Comment: Formatting tip:  You can typeset $\binom{n}{k}$ by typing `$\binom{n}{k}$`.

Comment: @Vanessa What do you mean?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig it is $69,609$

Comment: @Vanessa Is there some symmetry that I am supposed to see?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof of  $\sum_{0 \le k \le t} {t-k \choose r}{k \choose s}={t+1 \choose r+s+1}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73015/proof-of-sum-0-le-k-le-t-t-k-choose-rk-choose-s-t1-choose-rs1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The left side is how many ways to choose $a+b+1$ objects from $n+1$ objects.

We have to see why the right side is the same thing. Let $S=\{0, \ldots, n\}$, our set of $n+1$ objects. We want to count the number of ways to choose $C\subset S$ with $|C|=a+b+1$.  Suppose that we will choose $C=\{n_0, \ldots, n_{a+b}\}$ with $n_0<\ldots <n_{a+b}$.  We will choose in stages.

Stage $1$: Choose $n_a$.  Let $k$ denote the value of $n_a$. Note that $0\leqslant k\leqslant n$.

Stage $2$: Choose $n_0, \ldots, n_{a-1}$ from $\{0, \ldots, k-1\}$.  There are $\binom{k}{a}$ ways to do this.

Stage $3$: Choose $n_{a+1}, \ldots, n_{a+b}$ from $\{k+1, \ldots, n\}$. There are $\binom{n-k}{b}$ ways to do this.

Each $C\subset S$ arises in one and only one way from this sequence of choices, so the sum of all possible ways to choose in stages $1$-$3$, which is $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{k}{a}\binom{n-k}{b}$, is equal to the number of ways to choose $C\subset S$ with $|C|=a+b+1$, which is $\binom{n+1}{a+b+1}$.

Answer (score 1):

> An algebraic approach. We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{k}{a}\binom{n-k}{b}}
> &=\sum_{k=a}^{n-b}\binom{k}{a}\binom{n-k}{b}\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{n-a-b}\binom{k+a}{a}\binom{n-a-k}{b}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{n-a-b}\binom{k+a}{k}\binom{n-a-k}{n-a-b-k}\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{n-a-b}\binom{-a-1}{k}\binom{-b-1}{n-a-b-k}(-1)^{n-a-b}\tag{4}\\
> &=\binom{-a-b-2}{n-a-b}(-1)^{n-a-b}\tag{5}\\
> &=\binom{n+1}{n-a-b}\tag{6}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\binom{n+1}{a+b+1}}\tag{7}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim follows.

**Comment:**

- In (1) we restrict lower and upper index respecting that $\binom{p}{q}=0$ if $p<q$.
- In (2) we shift the index to start with $k=0$.
- In (3) we use the binomial identity $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p}{p-q}$.
- In (4) we use $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$.
- In (5) we apply the *[Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity)*.
- In (6) we use $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$ as in (3).
- In (7) we use $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p}{p-q}$ as in (4).

Answer (score 0):

The summand represents the number of ways to choose $a+b+1$ numbers from $1,...,n+1$ such that the $(a+1)$-th smallest number equals $k$.

When you add for all possible $k$, you get the total number of ways to choose $a+b+1$ from $n+1$ which is the LHS.